# How to improve openAI Semantic search speed

Tags: openai-api, embedding, openaiembeddings, semantic-search, similarity-search

I have a database(currently a json file) of keywords and their embedding data that i created with openAI's embedding.
What i am trying to do is a similarity search with the input keyword.
So In my current flow when i enter a keyword firstly it is embedded and its compared with the embeddings of data from my database.
What i have observed is when i add ten-thousands of data the similarity finding process takes too much time.
What is a good solution i can implement to get faster results even when there is millions of embedding data in my database.

I have seen about implementing faiss by meta.
But not sure if that is the proper solution
Below is the similarity function i currently use

```
def cosine_similarity(a, b):
            return np.dot(a, b) / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b))
similarities = [cosine_similarity(embedding, embedding_query) for embedding in embeddings]
```

Currently embedding data is read from a json file like below

```
        with open("data_a_b_j.json", "r") as f:
            embedding_data = json.load(f)

        # Extract embeddings and corresponding descriptions from the loaded data
        embeddings = [item["embedding"] for item in embedding_data]
```

Comment: Please avoid using local words like `lakh` because not everyone understands them.